# what does event inside the interface mean?

Tags: c#, .net

I know the class implementing an interface must implement all its method. But what does event inside the interface mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that the type must implement the event - so that clients can subscribe to those events.

Think of events as pairs of methods (add/remove) just as properties have get/set. Just as you can have properties in interfaces, you can have events: the implementation has to provide the appropriate add/remove methods and the metadata to tie them to the event. In C# this can be done using field-like events:

```
public event EventHandler EventFromInterface;
```

or with explicit add/remove methods:

```
public event EventHandler EventFromInterface
{
    add { ... }
    remove { ... }
}
```

Comment: Raising the event is also necessary, can you give one scenario where defining event without raising is of any help design wise?

Comment: Unrelated observation -- it's interesting how there's been at least 3-4 questions regarding events (and method pairs) in less than an hour or so!

Comment: @Lambert: I think they're far from unrelated :) I'm guessing that the original question has basically spawned these ones...

Comment: @Akash: See my response in the other answer... it's not a great idea to split comment threads like this.

Answer (score 0):

It means anything implementing that interface must raise that event. Pretty much the same as a Method or Property within an interface.

Comment: I think "raise" is an inappropriate word here. There's nothing forcing the event to be raised anywhere - but the class has to provide an implementation of add/remove for callers to use for subscription/unsubscription.

Comment: I'm picky but it actually means the implementer has to define the event (and maybe never raise it)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, raise is perfect word here, because if implementer does not raise the event, event is useless, neither child class or public access can raise the event.

Comment: @Akash: Imagine an interface for a file system, which could raise an event if a new file was added. Now imagine an implementation of that interface for a read-only device: it would have to implement the event, but it would never have to raise it.